# How to insert a TabularInline on ModelForm with crispy-forms and django

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to insert a TabularInline section in a form with a one-to-one relationship.

Here is the model I want to see "tabular inlined" in my Data form:

```
class DataLanguage(models.Model):
    data = models.ForeignKey(Data, related_name='languages')
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

The fact is that I want the same behavior than in the admin sectionWith the '+' button to add as many field as the user wants, and all that with crispy forms.

PS: Sorry for my english, I'm french.